# Value of one TextInput changes when user change value of other

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create a weight calculator where user can enter weight in KG or LB and value of the other input will change automatically. For example: user enter in KG input 100 and LB accepts value 198. I tried to give to TextInputs's default value value of entered input, but it doesn't work.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: I do not understand the question, from neither the title nor the description. Please elaborate, and also include the relevant code for the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: you are making a converter for KG and LB,
you have 2 input fields, when you change the value in first, you want to show the result in the second (vise versa).
If you want to change values in input fields you need to have controlled components which means you will set values with your state values.

For a short example (in ReactJS but the concept is the same):

```
import React from "react";

export default class Converter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0
    };
  }

  onChangeValue1 = value1 => {
    this.setState({ value1: value1, value2: value1 * 2 });
  };

  onChangeValue2 = value2 => {
    this.setState({ value1: value2 / 2, value2: value2 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.value1}
          onChange={e => this.onChangeValue1(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          value={this.state.value2}
          onChange={e => this.onChangeValue2(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```